use effect and afterNextRender together
I have a signal effect that I want to run only in the browser (and nothing in the server)
but both effect and afterNextRender require being run from the injection context
so running this code
effect(() => {
  afterNextRender(() => {
    // ...
  });
});

throw ERROR Error: NG0203: afterNextRender() can only be used within an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
and running
afterNextRender(() => {
  effect(() => {
    // ...
  });
});

throw ERROR Error: NG0203: effect() can only be used within an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
